# Getting an Android App working on Android 4+

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, ionic-framework, android-sdk-manager

I have built an Android app and it work on Android 5+ fine and also on Android 6. However on a Samsung tab 2 which runs Android 4.0.3, it will not run at all.

My SDK references Version 23 as the build but I do appear to have other previous versions installed too if you see a gif of my SDK installs.

What do I need to get compatibility from Android 4+ upwards to 6+?

Here is an animated gif of my SDK installtions on my Windows 8.1 PC

https://doc-0k-58-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/3j8cv73604l8fr6lnv9jtes7d1iia283/odp4i233fojbl1e4nn9elj2lp24d8sq1/1461592800000/06264479721830385231/06264479721830385231/0B3ArIuPt8mKRWFRmQ05rWEotb0E?e=view&nonce=fvo34pc7ag5u6&user=06264479721830385231&hash=ld0g2si7lv0u9avhsn48fjtnq99cqbqc

Answer (score 0):

From the Ionic Framework documentation:

> Ionic targets iPhone and Android devices (currently). We support iOS
>   7+, and Android 4.1+. However, since there are a lot of different
>   Android devices, it’s possible certain ones might not work

Since you are using Android 4.0.3, it will not work.

Source: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html